# Generate a Windows executable with Install4J and JDK11 works alone

Tags: install4j, exe4j

I am migrating my app from JDK 8 to JDK 11.
During my development on IntelliJ IDE, I have to add some VM parameters in order to start correctly my app.

Something like :

```
-Xms1G
-Xmx3G
--add-exports
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.util=ALL-UNNAMED
...
```

But when I generate ".exe" with Install4J 7 or Exe4J 7, I don't need to add any "--add-exports" params.
It works "alone".

Someone kwows why ?
Is it possible that, at the execution, my app will fail because of missiong one of these args ?

Regards.

Comment: Is your application modular with a module-info class? Then IntelliJ is using the module path. install4j only uses the module path if you explicitly configure the module path on the "Java invocation" step of the launcher wizard.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer